# Real analysis problem (solved one direction, struggling with the other one).

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Given a non-constant sequence $a_n$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\left|a_{n+1}-a_n\right|<q^n$ ($q>0$), prove that $a_n$ **necessarily** converges **if and only if** $q<1$

One direction I've proven successfully:

> Let $0<q<1$. Using the given data, it can be shown that, for $m>n$:
> $$\:\left|a_m-a_n\right|\:=\:\left|\left(a_m-a_{m-1}\right)+\left(a_{m-1}+a_{m-2}\right)+...+\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)\right|\le \:\left|a_m-a_{m-1}\right|+\left|a_{m-1}+a_{m-2}\right|+...+\left|a_{n+1}-a_n\right|\le \:q^{m-1}+q^{m-2}+...+q^n=_{geometric\:progression\:sum}\frac{q^n\left(1-q^{m-n}\right)}{1-q}=\frac{q^n-q^m}{1-q}$$
> Since $0<q<1$, it is easily verifiable that $\frac{q^n-q^m}{1-q}$ is
> always positive. Let $b_n=\frac{q^n}{1-q}$, so:
> $$\left|a_m-a_n\right|\le
> \frac{q^n-q^m}{1-q}=\left|\frac{q^n-q^m}{1-q}\right|=\left|b_n-b_m\right|$$
> Since $0<q<1$, $\lim _{n\to \infty }\:q^n=0$, and simple arithmetic
> will yield that $\lim _{n\to \infty }\:b_n=0$ as well. $b_n$ is
> convergent, therefore by the Cauchy criterion: $$\forall ϵ>0,\:\exists
> > N\in \mathbb{R},\:\forall n,m>N,\:\left|b_n-b_m\right|<ϵ$$ And so:
> $$\left|a_m-a_n\right|\le \left|b_n-b_m\right|<ϵ$$ And $a_n$ is
> convergent by the Cauchy criterion.

The other direction (convergence yields $q<1$) is the one I'm still struggling with. I thought about trying contradiction - assuming $q>1$ and showing that $a_n$ diverges (with $q=1$ as a special case to be handled separately, as it renders impossible the use of the geometric sum formula I used earlier), but things don't develop in a satisfactory manner. Any help or guidance for that direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: The *only if* part is false. A constant sequence converges, though it satisfies the condition for any $q \gt 0$.

Comment: Yes, it's negligence on my part. The intention was for non-constant sequences.

Comment: The *only if* part is still false. For example, the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$ but it satisfies the condition for any $q \ge 1$.

Comment: In fact for any convergent sequence, the inequality holds with $q=1$(so obviously also for $q\geq 1$) once $n$ is sufficiently large. This direction is just wrong.

Comment: You are all right, I was wrongly quoting the question apparently, I don't have it written nearby so it's strictly from memory. I fixed it now and verified it's true.

Comment: @Blabla What is the difference between the way you wrote it "*$a_n$ **necessarily** converges **if and only if** $q<1$*" and simply "*if $q \lt 1$ then $a_n$ converges*"? If you mean to show that $a_n$ *could* possibly diverge when $q \ge 1$ then just take an arithmetic progression with common difference $\lt 1$, or $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{3}$.

Comment: The question would make sense if you replaced $\left|a_{n+1}-a_n\right|<q^n$ with $\left|a_{n+1}-a_n\right| = q^n$